# Pointers as member data fields in C++ structs

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

void printArray(int A[], int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

struct Array {
    int *A;
    int size;
    int length;
};

void display(Array *arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr->length; i++) {
        cout << arr->A[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void fillArray(Array *arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr->length; i++) {
        cin >> arr->A[i];
    }
}

void add(Array *arr, int x) {
    if(arr->length < arr->size) {
        arr->A[++arr->length] = x;
    }
}

int main() {
    Array arr;
    cout << "arr.size before initializing: " << arr.size << "\n"; // gives a garbage value
    cout << "Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin >> arr.size;
    cout << "Output of arr variable &arr: " << &arr << "\n";
    arr.A = new int[arr.size];
    cout << "arr.length before initializing: " << arr.length << "\n"; // gives garbage value
    cout << "How many elements do you want to enter: ";
    cin >> arr.length;
    fillArray(&arr); //This is not pass by value but pass by reference because 
    display(&arr); // this function displays the values of arr
    add(&arr, 15);
    cout << "The length of the array after adding: " << arr.length << "\n";
    display(&arr);
    printArray(arr.A, arr.length);
}
```

The output of this program is like this:

```
$ ./array_adt 
arr.size before initializing: -140717888
Enter the size of the array: 10
Output of arr variable &arr: 0x7ffe4e0ec040
arr.length before initializing: 21932
How many elements do you want to enter: 5
4 6 7 3 2 
4   6   7   3   2   
The length of the array after adding: 6
4   6   7   3   2   0   
4   6   7   3   2   0
```

I am highly confused why the element 15 isn't added to the array of the struct (which is actually a pointer which is initialised to an array in the heap). If someone can throw light on this it would be great for a many people as well as for understanding c++ concepts in depth.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: A well-formed program is not allowed to read the value of an uninitialized variable. To do so is to make the program's behavior undefined. It means the compiler can do all sorts of things you wouldn't want when translating your code. Remove all lines that print uninitialized variables, they make for bad code even when not causing problems.

Comment: you mean all the lines where I am printing the arrays ? i.e function `display` and `printArray` ?

Comment: I mean "arr.size before initializing" - you read arr.size here while it still has a indeterminate value. The C++ standard disallows it, on pain of undefined behavior.

Comment: I am just learning C++ the hard way thats all :) haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr->A[++arr->length] = x;
```

should be

```
arr->A[arr->length++] = x;
```

Array indexes start at zero in C++, so the first element *past the end* of an array `arr` of size `N` is `arr[N]`. In other words `15` did get added to the array, just not in the right place.

Also your code leaks memory because the array allocated in `main` is never deleted. Correctly allocating dynamic memory is a big (and very important) topic. Consult your favourite C++ book, in particular you should research the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: also there is memory leak

Comment: This is true, but one problem at a time I guess. A full explanation of how to correctly handle dynamic allocation in classes is more than I want to give.

Comment: IMO memory leaks should not be ignored in any situation. It would be nice if you add it to your answer for those who read it later.

Comment: aah yes such a silly mistake, oh yes I am aware of the memory leak currently wanted to understand this concept of declaring arrays inside structs. adding a `delete []arr.A` at the end of `main` works I think.